# Does Shot-Spread Reduction affect the Luna Blaster?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

While playing Side Order with Murch's Palette, I was offered a floor with the Shot-Spread Reduction chip which "reduces the shot spread on your main weapon." The main weapon for Murch's Palette is the Luna Blaster, which doesn't have any spread as far as I am aware.

What does Shot-Spread Reduction do on the Luna Blaster? Does it have any effect?

Comment: Hard to tell. It could be related to shot-scatter reduction, a parameter that was modified in a [previous update](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Luna_Blaster#Version_History_3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Luna Blaster has the following properties:

- Shots cannot ever deviate from the inner reticle while on the ground.
- The angle its shots can deviate while in the air is 10 degrees.
  (source: https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Luna_Blaster

So the Shot-Spread Reduction only reduces the angle of the shots when jumping.